# Html5 & CSS3 - unifying sidebar and mainContent

Tags: html, css

image link - [webpage image](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-Wtr_WJq-vwU/Ulj47XIuRlI/AAAAAAAAAg0/sNtrZ9rT8Zs/w1278-h627-no/Capture.PNG)

I want to remove all the spaces but can't do so.
i also want the sidebar to be of the same height as Content
Thankyou!

I don't know what's wrong with it
should i make a single sidebar instead of 3?

CODE
HTML5 and CSS3 code
http://www.mediafire.com/download/70p421je5uv2a4m/Theme.rar

THank you!!! :D

Comment: i suggest to u to give like this .mainContent{background:#fff}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `background` for element that `contain` your `sidebar` and content:

```
<div style="background:#fff">
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="sidebar"></div>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/Chovanec/pen/hcAmH

Comment: thanks! but how do I remove the space above and below header?

Answer (score 1):

In case you want the height of the content responsive, and the sidebar change responsive along with it, you can try a jQuery solution

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {

var y = $("#content").outerHeight();
$("#sidebar").css({"height": y});  

$( window ).resize(function() {
var y = $("#content").outerHeight();
$("#sidebar").css({"height": y}); 
});
}); 
</script>
```